# How to enforce password policy change in apache http server?

Tags: apache, http

We are using HTTP server to route the request to Winchill PLM. There is a requirement to force the user to change the password once the login first time into the PLM. In order to achieve this, PTC ( Winchill PLM Vendor) posted a note stating that this can be done through Apache setting.

Could somebody help us on what is the setting to be done in Apache httpd conf file so that Apache validates the auth data with Winchill directory server and also force the user to change if it is first time login.

Answer (score 0):

> PTC ( Winchill PLM Vendor) posted a note stating that this can be done through Apache setting

hmmmm. but didn't tell you *how* to do this? Is this software you've paid for? If they state their application works with Apache then they should be able to tell you how to do this.

But, rather alarmingly, it is worth noting that the httpd does not provide any authentication functionality - [that is handled by the auth modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) (some of which are bundled with httpd). And you've not told us which auth module you are using. The simplest solution is file based - but it [does not provide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) a method for setting password expiry.

A further issue is that regardless of which auth module you use, you are constrained to using HTTP (basic or digest) authentication if you implement authentication as an apache module - this provides a means for capturing a username and password - but [not for negotiating a change of password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617). That's not just an issue on the webserver side - it's also how the browser will handle authentication.

> route the request to Winchill PLM

That's not a very meaningful description of the architecture. I point this out here, as I suspect that the system *might* be handling authentication at the application tier (i.e. prompting for a username/password in the html) and that *might* require a specific configuration on the webserver, and it *might* provide a facility for password management.

But based on the information you've provided, either you or the vendor are *very* confused about how this application integrates with httpd.